# permutations with a given condition!

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

What will be the number of permutations of n different things, taken r at a time,when p particular things is to be always included in each arrangement? I know the answer to this question but could not reach to the logic behind this.How to tackle these permutations where conditions are given?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming we have $r\geq p$. In that case, one just needs to choose $r-p$ other items to go with the $p$ required ones, and then permute all $r$ of those in every possible way. That gives us the formula

$\binom{n-p}{r-p}\cdot r!$